# How to strip time from true date?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to strip the timestamp from a true date.

From 31/11/2015  12:00:00 AM to 31/11/2015.

I use the below code without using Text to Columns (staying away from it):

```
Sub strpTime()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR
        With Range("B" & i)
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
            .Value = Int(.Value)
        End With
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The runtime to execute is slow as I have almost 4,000 rows. Is there some other way, without using TexttoColumns?

Comment: What's wrong with VBA's [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx)? (btw, please do not use ambiguous DMY/MDY examples)

Comment: I have a lot of columns and already had macro on other columns. So if I use TexttoColums, I have to go back on my macro and move the column accordingly on each column I have macro. PS: Sorry for the ambiguous date examples. I didn't realized it.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me and should be fast on 4000 rows (for me it takes less than a second).

Comment: Why can't you use rounddown directly in the worksheet? That will strip the time part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab all raw [Range.Value2 properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) into a variant array and perform the time truncation in-memory. Once the array elements have been adjusted, dump the new values back into the worksheet and set the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx).

```
Sub strpTime()
    Dim lr As Long, d As Long, vDATs As Variant

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        With .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            vDATs = .Value2
            For d = LBound(vDATs, 1) To UBound(vDATs, 1)
                vDATs(d, 1) = Int(vDATs(d, 1))
            Next d
            .Value = vDATs
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
        End With

    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Stick with the `Int(...)` function conversion. Both `CInt` and `CLng` have rounding tendancies which might push a date ahead if the time was after 12:00.

Answer (score 3):

Working with an array would be quicker:

```
Sub strpTime()
  Dim rg As Range, data()

  ' load the values in an array
  Set rg = Range("B2").Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
  data = rg.value

  ' strip the time if the cell is not empty
  For i = 1 To UBound(data)
    If data(i, 1) <> Empty Then data(i, 1) = data(i, 1) Or 0
  Next i

  ' copy the values back to the sheet
  rg.value = data
  rg.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
End Sub
```

Comment: both version of codes with @Jeeped are fantastic! Thank you for these and I will try both which is better. Much appreciated of your inputs. Cheers!